# Python PIL: How to FIll a Image with a copyright logo like this?

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library, photoshop, copyright-display

I need to protect my photos by filling them with copyright logos. My OS is Ubuntu 10.10 and Python 2.6. I intend to use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).

Supposed I have a copyright logo like this ([You can do this in Photoshop easily](http://www.photoshopessentials.com/photo-effects/copyright/)):

[image: water mark logo]

and a picture like this:

[image: Original Picture]

**I want to use PIL to get copyrighted pictures like the following (Fill the original pic with pattern):**

[image: Copyrighted Picture]

**and Final Result by altering the opacity of logos:**

[image: Final Result]

Is there any function in PIL that can do this? Any hint?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's a recipe that might be of some help, it only adds a single watermark though so you would have to modify it http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362879-watermark-with-pil/

Comment: These links might help: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/362879-watermark-with-pil/ .. http://hasanatkazmi.blogspot.com/2009/06/putting-watermark-to-images-in-batch.html

Answer (score 6):

PIL is certainly capable of this. First you'll want to create an image that contains the repeated text. It should be, oh, maybe twice the size of the image you want to watermark (since you'll need to rotate it and then crop it). You can use `Image.new()` to create such an image, then `ImageDraw.Draw.text()` in a loop to repeatedly plaster your text onto it, and the image's `rotate()` method to rotate it 15 degrees or so. Then crop it to the size of the original image using the `crop()` method of the image.

To combine it first you'll want to use `ImageChops.multiply()` to superimpose the watermark  onto a copy of the original image (which will have it at 100% opacity) then `ImageChops.blend()` to blend the watermarked copy with the original image at the desired opacity.

That should give you enough information to get going -- if you run into a roadblock, post code showing what you've got so far, and ask a specific question about what you're having difficulty with.

Comment: is there a way to temporarily add watermark while displaying instead of saving a copy

Answer (score 2):

Just a sample：

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PIL import Image

def fill_watermark():
    im = Image.open('a.jpg').convert('RGBA')
    bg = Image.new(mode='RGBA', size=im.size, color=(255, 255, 255, 0))
    logo = Image.open('logo.png')  # .rotate(45) if you want, bg transparent
    bw, bh = im.size
    iw, ih = logo.size
    for j in range(bh // ih):
        for i in range(bw // iw):
            bg.paste(logo, (i * iw, j * ih))
    im.alpha_composite(bg)
    im.show()
    
fill_watermark()
```